# Deactivating command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command block that teleports you to another place - it is permanently on (because of redstone), so whenever I get close to the command block, it teleports me - it is really annoying. How can I deactivate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can run a Minecraft server locally[[1]][1][[2]][2], set `enable-command-block=false` in [server.properties][3] (if it isn't already) and then just join the server IP `localhost`, go to the command block and break it.
- You can change the command in the command block using NBTEdit: Open the save folder with it, go to `region\<the region file with the command block in it>\<the chunk with the command block in it>\Level\TileEntitites\13 entries\Command`, double click, change it, "OK", then "Save" in the toolbar.
- You can get roughly the coordinates of the command block, then subtract 15 from each axis for the first set of coordinates and add 15 for the second set: `/fill <x y z> <x y z> air 0 replace command_block`
- You can use MCEdit. I can't give you instructions on that, because I haven't used it yet. But it's probably pretty easy to use.
  [1]: https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
  [2]: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server
  [3]: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties

Answer (score 0):

You could use McEdit, or go as close as possible to the command block, press F3 (fn + f3 on a mac), and find out the coordinates of the command block or the Redstone powering it, click t and type `/setblock x y z air` (replace x y and z with the command block or redstone coordinates)